# Imacros: Check if text exists

Tags: imacros

I need help with iMacros.

I have a task which consists of two parts:

1) Go to a website and fill out a form.

```
URL GOTO=https://example.com/registration
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:NQKtn CONTENT=ggg
```

2) Check if the text `Mytext` exists (which has to appear after filling out the form).

The task of the script is to save the string `ggg` to `file.txt` if the text is found, and to pass it if it's not.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks very much!

Comment: Use JS scripting. Search on stack of examples.

Answer (score 2):

Example with Javascript and iMacros for Firefox:

```
var FilePath = "c:\\yourfile.txt";
var your_newtext = "ggg";

var macro = "CODE:";
macro += "URL GOTO=https://example.com/registration\n";
macro += "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES\n";
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:NQKtn CONTENT="+your_newtext+"\n";
macro += "WAIT SECONDS = 0.1\n";
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:NQKtn EXTRACT=TXT\n";
iimPlay(macro);
var last_extract = iimGetLastExtract();
var msg;
if(last_extract == "#EANF#" || last_extract == ""){
    msg = "NOT FOUND\n";
}else{
    msg = "FOUND: "+last_extract+"\n";
}
var file_o = imns.FIO.openNode(FilePath);
imns.FIO.appendTextFile(file_o, msg);
```